# Setting default setting to 'no proxy' in Selenium Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

Whenever I open Firefox using Selenium in python using the command

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The default proxy configuration is set to "use system proxy setting". I have not configured any proxy in the system. Still whenever the browser opens, it says "The proxy server is refusing connection".

How do I open the browser so that the default proxy setting is set to "no proxy" ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post from my memory

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.Kind','Direct')
webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

To use the default profile you have to specify it

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path_to_profile_in_your_pc)
webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, but profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 0) did.

Comment: Yes, "0" means "No Proxy". Details see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type